# How to invoke methods of objects with different types with same name and different return values?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, jaxb

I have a lot of classes generated by JAXB and I can not change them. I have to get the values of the properties for some of their objects in a pretty similar way and then populate table with them. Here I am giving the code for two such getter methods:

```
private String getPropertyIdentifierStringOrNull(IdentifierType obj)
{
    if(obj != null)
        return obj.getValue();
    else
        return null;
}

private XMLGregorianCalendar getPropertyXMLGregorianCalendarOrNull(DateType obj)
{
    if(obj != null)
        return obj.getValue();
    else
        return null;
}
```

DateType and IdentifierType do not have common supperclass, and as in this example code return values can be of different types.

I am trying to write one method instead of bunch of these. I've come up with this solution using generic method with the reflection:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T getPropertyOrNull(Object obj)
{
    if(obj != null)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T) obj.getClass().getMethod("getValue").invoke(obj);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is this good way of doing this kind of calls or is there any better solution?

Comment: I think it's perfect. As long as you cannot add a superinterface for these classes, you need reflection.

Comment: Thanks @Tamas, you were extremely fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use reflection for this. Instead, you could do it with a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) that extracts the desired property from the given object, as follows:

```
static <T, U> U getPropertyOrNull(T obj, Function<? super T, ? extends U> extractor) {
    return obj != null ? extractor.apply(obj) : null;
}
```

You could use it this way:

```
IdentifierType identifier = new IdentifierType();
DateType date = new DateType();

String identifierValue = getPropertyOrNull(identifier, IdentifierType::getValue);

XMLGregorianCalendar dateValue = getPropertyOrNull(date, DateType::getValue);
```

Besides not using reflection, the advantage of this approach is that it's type safe, i.e. if you invoke the method with `IdentifierType` and `DateType::getValue` arguments, you'll get a compilation error.